# Kafka + Avro + Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, avro

I want to send messages by producer and getting them by consumer. It has to be in avro, but i dont know how to do it. Take a look:

```
schema = { "type":"record", "name":"myrecord", "fields": [{"name":"typ","type":"string"}, {"name":"pred","type":"int"}

producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['xxxx:xxxx'],value_serializer = avro.schema.parse(json.dumps(schema)))

for i in range(100):
    message = {"typ":"sth","pred":i}
    producer.send("xxxx", value=message)
```

Can you help me how to do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer
import io
from avro.schema import Parse
from avro.io import DatumWriter, DatumReader, BinaryEncoder, BinaryDecoder

# Create a Kafka client ready to produce messages
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_address,
                         security_protocol="...", ...)

# Get the schema to use to serialize the message
schema = Parse(open(FILENAME_WHERE_YOU_HAVE_YOUR_AVRO_SCHEMA, "rb").read())

# serialize the message data using the schema
buf = io.BytesIO()
encoder = BinaryEncoder(buf)
writer = DatumWriter(writer_schema=schema)
writer.write(myobject, encoder)
buf.seek(0)
message_data = (buf.read())

# message key if needed
key = None

# headers if needed
headers = []

# Send the serialized message to the Kafka topic
producer.send(topicname,
              message_data,
              key,
              headers)
producer.flush()
```

Comment: Thank youuu so much!

Answer (score 0):

Using `kafka-python`, the `value_serializer` needs to be a function of the **value**, not a parsed Avro schema.

For example

```
from avro.io import DatumWriter

schema_def = { ... }
schema = avro.schema.parse(json.dumps(schema_def).encode('utf-8'))

def serialize(value):
    writer = DatumWriter()
    # TODO: add schema to writer
    # TODO: write value payload to writer
    # TODO: return writer to bytes

producer = KafkaProducer(value_serializer=serialize)
```

This is more work than you really need to do. Look at the `confluent-kafka-python` example code instead - https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/blob/master/examples/avro_producer.py